# How to output Rails image_tag with Vue class binding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

How do I output an image tag which has a bound class from Rails for use by Vue?

I need the class to be bound to Vue as follows:

```
<img src="triangle.png" :class="{'asc': !sort_by_desc, 'desc': sort_by_desc}"/>
```

Converting that to Rails syntax (to benefit from asset pipeline), the following causes a (Rails) syntax error:

```
<%= image_tag ("triangle.png", v-bind:class: "{'asc': !sort_by_desc, 'desc': sort_by_desc}") %>
```

I have tried other combinations to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's this

```
<%= image_tag "triangle.png", "v-bind:class": "{'asc': !sort_by_desc, 'desc': sort_by_desc}" %>
```

You should turn `v-bind:class` into a string `"v-bind:class"` with those double-quotes.

Also, this is not a Vue issue.

Comment: Thanks, @ytbryan. Seems the quotes around the class name were what I needed!

Comment: @MSC glad that I helped :)

Comment: btw, it seems that you are working with Vue and Rails too. Maybe you will be interested in http://github.com/vueonrails/vueonrails